# Conditional expectation calculation with a binary variable

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X=\{0, 1\}$ is a binary random variable, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Z$ is another random variable. I get
\begin{equation}
E\left(\frac{X}{E(X)}Z|Y, X\right)=\frac{X}{E(X)}E(Z|Y, X). \qquad\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
But is the following correct?
\begin{equation}
E\left(\frac{X}{E(X)}Z|Y, X\right)=\frac{X}{E(X)}E(Z|Y, X=1). \qquad(2)
\end{equation}
By the way, this is not a homework problem.
If $X=1$, the LHS of (2) is $E\left(\frac{1}{E(X)}Z|Y, X\right)$, and the RHS of (2) is $\frac{1}{E(X)}E(Z|Y, X=1)$. LHS=RHS?

Comment: By definition, the left hand side is a random variable: it can vary with $Y$ and $X.$ The right hand side of your second formula does not vary with $X.$  Unless, then, the first formula does not really depend on $X,$ these formulas cannot be equivalent.

Comment: I might misunderstand your point, but why the right hand side of the second formula does not vary with $: \frac{X}{E(X)}E(Z|Y, X=1)$? There is a factor $X$ indeed.

Comment: It explicitly specifies $X=1$!

Comment: X is not part of the expectation. $E(XY|X=1)=E(Y|X=1)$, but $X E(Y|X=1)!=E(Y|X=1)$ in general.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your comment and your question.  Regardless, in $(1),$ $X$ is explicitly part of the expectation: you are conditioning on it. I urge you to simplify your question ($Y$ plays no essential role) and consider explicitly a special instance, such as when $Z$ is binary.

Comment: My comment is about your answer, which in turn is related to my question. I have no intention to change my question unless it is not clear.

Comment: A conditional expectation should be written as $E[\cdot | \cdot ]$. Having $(Z|Y,X)$ as a term inside the expectation doesn't make sense

Comment: I made editorial changes to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith Ok now it's clearer, and yes it does seem to be correct, as long as you remember that $X$ can only take the values 0 and 1

Comment: Agreed: the notational clarification helps immensely.

Comment: It is not clear why (2) holds. I have modified the question.

Comment: @JohnSmith $X=1$ in (2) means that the expectation is conditional on $X=1$ so RHS=LHS. and if $X=0$ both sides are zero.